Generation of 'arbitrary' contract method name from selector on etherscan
I was looking at this contract 0xbaDc0dEfAfCF6d4239BDF0b66da4D7Bd36fCF05A, and I saw that the transactions called a method named I Got Rekt Z5534023222745275079. I suppose that this method name got bruteforced to match the selector, hence the Z5534023222745275079 suffix which looks like a nonce. Am I correct? If yes, why do all these fictitious methods' nonce (which can be found on several other contracts) start with Z? Is it because a specific software is used that always starts with Z? And how is the method name 'sent' to etherscan without having to verify the entire contract? Is it just sent to a selector database which etherscan relies on to get their method names?
